# Dynamically Get Zip Code on Shipping Form

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, zipcode

I would like to get the zip code after the user is done inputting.
I am using a One Page Checkout for this. I am currently using a code that get the zip code on the user information being saved on the system. By the way I would like to add the code on one of the custom module's model. is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. can you share you custom module code for the retrieve zip code?

Comment: @Abdul i am currently using this code: **$primaryAddress = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();$zipcode = $primaryAddress->getPostcode();**

Comment: but are you need when customer typing in zip code field right?

Comment: yes @Abdul I need that.

Comment: which One Page Checkout module are using right now?

Comment: @Abdul https://www.apptha.com/category/extension/magento/onestepcheckout <-- this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37703/discussion-between-abdul-and-alen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code on the OnePageCheckout Controller(IndexController.php):

```
$billing_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
```

and get the Zip Code:

```
$billing_data['postcode']
```

as you wish to use it on other module, just set it on the core session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsZipCode();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setZipCode($ZipCode);
```

and Get value from session in your module like:

```
$zipCode = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getZipCode();
```

this will allow you to get the Zip Code whenever the user is done inputting.